# Three phase commit protocol

Tags: database, transactions, protocols, commit

I'm trying to understand the three phase commit protocol by reading the wiki page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_commit_protocol#Motivation). In the description for the diagram I posted below, it says the following: "If the **coordinator succeeds in the prepared state, it will move to the commit state.** However if the coordinator times out while waiting for an acknowledgement from a cohort, it will abort the transaction. In the case where all acknowledgements are received, the **coordinator moves to the commit state as well**."

Is that a typo where it says "coordinator moves to the commit state as well?" Isn't it already in the commit state? Does it mean "the cohort moves to the commit state as well?" Seems like it kind of says the same thing twice.

[image]

Comment: This question might be a little more appropriate over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com, as it is somewhat more theoretical and process-oriented than specifically code-oriented.

Comment: Okay I will post it over there.

Comment: Read the talk page, there are problems with the article. Suggest you google some other sources.

Comment: I understand that page has issues, but is "cohorts" the same thing as participant? Or what does it mean by cohorts? I don't see any mention of that in a text book I'm looking at, and the text book doesn't have enough info otherwise I would just stick purely to that.

Comment: What is your textbook? (You didn't @ me when there were multiple previous commenters so I did not get pinged. I just happened by.)